# One-word synonym for 'out of context'?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

[Context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/30625/8712):

> Here, because 'him' refers to another human suspect and 'you' to British Army Major Rachel Dalton (portrayed by Rhona Mitra), http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/downwind doesn't make sense and is **out of context**.

Comment: @LePressentiment: I think your edit is less than ideal, in that you've linked to *your own previous use of "out of context"*. You're not a native speaker - but I am, and I don't think that is a very appropriate usage. Having said that, I think the most likely "synonym" in *your* contexct is simply ***irrelevant*** (which is not *exactly* the sense in which the expression *"out of context"* is normally used).

Answer (score 3):

The adjective [*incongruous*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+incongruous) describes something that is out of place.  Something that does not blend in with its surroundings.

It would fit well in your example context.

Answer (score 2):

**Noncontextual**

However, the best definition will depend on the context, since something taken out of context can be described by a slew of adjectives such as *misquoted, misconstrued*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer your question exactly (as it isn't even an adjective), but I was also looking for a word to describe "taking something out of context, and stumbled across the following:

> con·tex·to·my [kon-teks-tuh-mee]
>
> noun
>
> *The practice of misquoting someone by shortening the quotation or by leaving out surrounding words or sentences that would place the
>   quotation in context.*

Looks like a pretty good answer for the word you are looking for. Does it help?

For reference:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contextomy
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_quoting_out_of_context

Comment: I guarantee that not a single native speaker will know this word if you ask a thousand of them off the street :P

Comment: Haha. Maybe not a thousand, but I agree fully with your sentiment. It surprised me when I found it, and considering my appetite for unusual and obscure English words, my vocabulary would probably be somewhere above average (within reason, obviously — it would still probably look rather pitiful next to most scholars of the English language ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but there is a word that describes when you have used a word out of context when you really mean a similar-sounding word: **malapropism**

I did so recently when I accidentally substituted 'inert' for 'innate'.

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism).

Comment: A malapropism is a slip of the tongue usage of the wrong word.  It is not an out-of-context usage of the correct word.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the phrase "*out of context*" with the phrase "*isn't appropriate there*". From what I've understood you think the word "*downwind*" isn't the appropriate word to use in that context.

In cases when something is somewhere where it shouldn't be - isn't appropriate or suitable there (doesn't fit in) we use:

- inapt, inapplicable, inapposite, misplaced, Irrelevant

"**[Out of context](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/out_of_context)**" means '*Without the surrounding words or circumstances and so not fully understandable.*'

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use phrases rather than words. You can always change the formatting of a sentence to accommodate for the three-word adjective 'out-of-context'. In fact, that is arguably the best way to say it: the word 'non-contextual' dampens the meaning and sounds pretentious without adding value to any statement you could possibly throw it in.

Compare 'that's non-contextual' to `that's out-of-context' and let me know if you agree.

Comment: One word is always better than three words with the same meaning.

Answer (score -2):

> "non sequitur"

is useful in many instances of non-context.